# Escape and enclose by same symbol doesn't work

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with a nullable column:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, value INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, null);
```

I export it to csv using

```
SELECT * FROM test 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv' 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"'
```

The output file looks like this:

```
1,"N
```

Then I try to import it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE `test`.`test` 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

And it does't work and generates the following warning:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
Warning 1366: Incorrect integer value: '"N' for column 'value' at row 1
```

And it doesn't insert this row. For some reason escaping doesn't work for this case. It does work if field are escaped and enclosed by different symbols.

But I can't use different symbols because I can't change export query because I use Google Cloud SQL and export to csv can be done only from google web console without ability to edit the query.

I've seen multiple examples on the internet that double quote in both cases should work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So you're telling us that you _have_ to use double quote as an escape character?  Even if you could get that to work, I would avoid doing it.  Why exactly can't you use backslash?

Comment: If this was my problem, I probably would load the csv file into a good editor (or use `sed`, `awk` and associated tools) and try to work out a REGEX-REPLACE which replaces the string `"N` by the string `NULL`. Of course, that would not be easy since that string could occur as part of normal text as well. But in general, it should be feasible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes. I don't have a direct access to SQL server instance (similar to RDS if you are not familiar with google cloud). But I can create an export task in web console, I have only access to a part query before `INTO` clause and no additional options.

Comment: What you are describing is that NULLs cannot be supported in Google Cloud SQL and that seems unlikely.

Comment: If I click "export" with default options and then truncate and "import" the same file, it replaces all `null` values with `0` for int columns and `"N` for varchar columns